# Feeds importer not importing when image does not exist

Tags: feeds

I am importing a productfeed with Feed Importer.

All the items that has working images, will import. All the items where the images give a 404 and do not exist, it wont import the product at all.

How can i import these products, and set a default image?

Comment: Is image field mandatory in content type ? Can you make it not required and try the same ? Can you check the error logs in watch dog after importing ? Post here if you see any error logs for failed feed items...

Comment: The image field is not mandatory in the content type. The feeds importer gives this error at every item that cannot be imported: Download of http://www.bps4m.nl/images/ean/big/5030305514525.jpg failed with code 404. I think the problem is in the Feeds Importer, it does not want to import the item when the image cannot be downloaded.